# how to remove div from BeautifulSoup filter result

Tags: python-3.x

Now I am trying to remove div class from BeautifulSoup result like this:

```
response = requests.get(url)
            // success
            cnbeta_article_content = BeautifulSoup(response.content, "html.parser").find("div", {"class": "cnbeta-article-body"})
            // failed
            removed_share_content = BeautifulSoup(cnbeta_article_content, "html.parse").find("div", {"class": "article-share-code"}).decompose()
            result_text = removed_share_content.prettify()
            return result_text
```

first get div from class `cnbeta-article-body`, the delete div `article-share-code` from filtered result, but it seems not work. what should I do to fix it? this url is: `https://www.cnbeta.com/articles/tech/1097507.htm`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The html of `cnbeta-article-body` div is as follows

```
<div class="cnbeta-article-body">
<div class="article-summary">
<div class="topic"><a href="https://www.cnbeta.com/topics/741.htm" target="_blank"><img src="https://static.cnbetacdn.com/topics/9a78aa447fb90ef.png" title="æ‰‹æœº - OnePlus ä¸€åŠ "/></a></div>
<p>ä¸€åŠ å³å°†å‘å¸ƒå¹´åº¦æ——èˆ°ä¸€åŠ 9ç³»åˆ—ï¼Œéšç€æ–°æ——èˆ°çš„åˆ°æ¥ï¼Œä¸€åŠ 8ç³»åˆ—æœºåž‹ä»·æ ¼å¼€å§‹ä¸‹è°ƒã€‚ä»Šå¤©ï¼Œä¸€åŠ å®£å¸ƒï¼Œ<strong>ä¸€åŠ 8 Proæœ€é«˜ä¼˜æƒ 1000å
ƒï¼Œèµ·å”®ä»·åªè¦4599å
ƒï¼Œæ”¯æŒ24æœŸå
æ¯åˆ†æœŸ</strong>ï¼Œæä¾›é’ç©ºã€é»‘é•œã€è“è°ƒä¸‰ç§é
è‰²ã€‚</p> </div>
<div class="article-content" id="artibody">
<div class="article-global"><p><strong>è®¿é—®ï¼š</strong></p><p><a href="https://click.aliyun.com/m/1000245338/" target="_blank"><strong><span style="color: rgb(192, 0, 0);">2021é˜¿é‡Œäº‘ä¸Šäº‘é‡‡è´å£ï¼šé‡‡è´è¡¥è´´ã€å

å€¼è¿”åˆ¸ã€çˆ†æ¬¾æŠ¢å
ˆè´â€¦â€¦</span></strong></a></p></div> <div class="article-topic"><p>
<strong>è®¿é—®è´ä¹°é¡µé¢:</strong>
</p>
<p>
<a href="https://c.duomai.com/track.php?site_id=242986&amp;aid=942&amp;euid=&amp;t=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.oneplus.com" target="_blank">ä¸€åŠ è‡ªè¥æ——èˆ°åº—</a>
</p></div><p style="text-align:center"><img src="https://static.cnbetacdn.com/article/2021/0304/8158fddd4c92c53.jpg"/></p><p style="text-align: left;">ä¸€åŠ  8 Proæœ€å¤§çš„çœ‹ç‚¹ä¹‹ä¸€æ˜¯å±å¹•ï¼Œ<strong>å
¶å±å¹•å°ºå¯¸ä¸º6.78è‹±å¯¸ï¼Œåˆ†è¾¨çŽ‡ä¸º2K+ï¼Œåˆ·æ–°çŽ‡ä¸º120Hzï¼Œè§¦æŽ§é‡‡æ ·çŽ‡ä¸º240Hzï¼Œè¢«ç§°ä¹‹ä¸ºâ€œå±å¹•æœºçš‡â€ã€‚</strong></p><p style="text-align: left;">DisplayMateè¯„ä»·ä¸€åŠ 8 Proï¼š<strong>æ•™ç§‘ä¹¦èˆ¬å®Œ<a data-link="1" href="https://c.duomai.com/track.php?site_id=242986&amp;euid=&amp;t=https://mideajiadian.jd.com/" target="_blank">ç¾Žçš„</a>æ ¡å‡†ç²¾åº¦å’Œæ€§èƒ½è¡¨çŽ°</strong>ï¼Œåˆ›é€ 13é¡¹æ™ºèƒ½<a data-link="1" href="https://c.duomai.com/track.php?site_id=242986&amp;euid=&amp;t=https://shouji.jd.com/" target="_blank">æ‰‹æœº</a>æ˜¾ç¤ºè®°å½•ã€‚</p><p style="text-align: left;">è§„æ ¼æ–¹é¢ï¼Œä¸€åŠ 8 Proæè½½é«˜é€šéªé¾™865æ——èˆ°å¹³å°ï¼Œå‰ç½®1600ä¸‡åƒç´ ï¼ŒåŽç½®4800ä¸‡è¶
æ¸
å››æ‘„ï¼Œç”µæ± å®¹é‡ä¸º4510mAhï¼Œæ”¯æŒ30W Warpæ— çº¿é—ªå

ã€Warpé—ªå

30Tæœ‰çº¿å

ç”µã€‚</p><p style="text-align: left;">æ¤å¤–ï¼Œä¸€åŠ 8Tå
¨é¢çŽ°è´§å‘å”®ï¼Œèµ·å”®ä»·3399å
ƒï¼Œä¸€åŠ 8é™è‡³3299å
ƒã€‚</p><p style="text-align: center;"><a href="https://static.cnbetacdn.com/article/2021/0304/cfdb4208167012e.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="https://static.cnbetacdn.com/thumb/article/2021/0304/cfdb4208167012e.jpg"/></a><a href="https://static.cnbetacdn.com/article/2021/0304/e7bb8bbd2e5b913.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="https://static.cnbetacdn.com/thumb/article/2021/0304/e7bb8bbd2e5b913.jpg"/></a><a href="https://static.cnbetacdn.com/article/2021/0304/2e6cad84f505f43.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="https://static.cnbetacdn.com/thumb/article/2021/0304/2e6cad84f505f43.jpg"/></a><a href="https://static.cnbetacdn.com/article/2021/0304/b77d443a3761049.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="https://static.cnbetacdn.com/thumb/article/2021/0304/b77d443a3761049.jpg"/></a><a href="https://static.cnbetacdn.com/article/2021/0304/ea9ebd51f33109f.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="https://static.cnbetacdn.com/thumb/article/2021/0304/ea9ebd51f33109f.jpg"/></a><a href="https://static.cnbetacdn.com/article/2021/0304/db97040429b984a.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="https://static.cnbetacdn.com/thumb/article/2021/0304/db97040429b984a.jpg"/></a><a href="https://static.cnbetacdn.com/article/2021/0304/6a9943e38585768.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="https://static.cnbetacdn.com/thumb/article/2021/0304/6a9943e38585768.jpg"/></a><a href="https://static.cnbetacdn.com/article/2021/0304/06ceef5e21085e6.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="https://static.cnbetacdn.com/thumb/article/2021/0304/06ceef5e21085e6.jpg"/></a><a href="https://static.cnbetacdn.com/article/2021/0304/c052adf0ce81f58.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="https://static.cnbetacdn.com/thumb/article/2021/0304/c052adf0ce81f58.jpg"/></a><a href="https://static.cnbetacdn.com/article/2021/0304/5e3036dd27cbd45.jpg" target="_blank"><img src="https://static.cnbetacdn.com/thumb/article/2021/0304/5e3036dd27cbd45.jpg"/></a></p> </div>
<div class="tac">
<div class="tal cbv"><script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-3507708728694406";
/* cnBeta.COM æ–‡ç« é¡µæ–‡æœ«é€šæ  #1 */
google_ad_slot = "1385693419";
google_ad_width = 810;
google_ad_height = 100;
//-->
</script>
<script src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js" type="text/javascript">
</script></div>
<div class="tal cbv">
<a href="https://click.aliyun.com/m/1000245337/" target="_blank"><img src="https://static.cnbetacdn.com/article/2021/03/7bcc0f26b07694b.jpg"/></a>
</div>
<div class="tal cbv">
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-3507708728694406";
/* cnBeta.COM æ–‡ç« é¡µæ–‡æœ«é€šæ  #2 */
google_ad_slot = "8489727379";
google_ad_width = 810;
google_ad_height = 100;
//-->
</script>
<script src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
</div>
<div class="cbv810">
<div class="left500"><script type="text/javascript">
        (function() {
            var s = "_" + Math.random().toString(36).slice(2);
            document.write('<div style="" id="' + s + '"></div>');
            (window.slotbydup = window.slotbydup || []).push({
                id: "u4395341",
                container: s
            });
        })();
</script><script async="async" defer="defer" src="//cpro.baidustatic.com/cpro/ui/c.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
</div>
<div class="right300"><script type="text/javascript"><!--
google_ad_client = "ca-pub-3507708728694406";
/* cnBeta.COM V5 æ–‡ç« é¡µæ–‡æœ«ç”»ä¸ç”» #2 */
google_ad_slot = "5755245019";
google_ad_width = 300;
google_ad_height = 250;
//-->
</script>
<script src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js" type="text/javascript">
</script></div>
</div> </div>
<div class="article-share-code">
<div class="share-unit"><div class="share-btns bdsharebuttonbox"><a class="bds_tsina share-btn weibo" data-cmd="tsina" href="#" title="åˆ†äº«åˆ°æ–°æµªå¾®åš">æ–°æµªå¾®åš</a><a class="bds_qzone share-btn qzone" data-cmd="qzone" href="#" title="åˆ†äº«åˆ°QQç©ºé—´">QQç©ºé—´</a><a class="bds_tqq share-btn tqq" data-cmd="tqq" href="#" title="åˆ†äº«åˆ°è
¾è®¯å¾®åš">è
¾è®¯å¾®åš</a><a class="bds_sqq share-btn sqq" data-cmd="sqq" href="#" title="åˆ†äº«åˆ°QQå¥½å‹">QQå¥½å‹</a><a class="bds_weixin share-btn weixin" data-cmd="weixin" href="#" title="åˆ†äº«åˆ°å¾®ä¿¡">å¾®ä¿¡</a><a class="bds_douban share-btn douban" data-cmd="douban" href="#" title="åˆ†äº«åˆ°è±†ç“£ç½‘">è±†ç“£ç½‘</a><a class="bds_youdao share-btn youdao" data-cmd="youdao" href="#" title="åˆ†äº«åˆ°æœ‰é“äº‘ç¬”è®°">æœ‰é“äº‘ç¬”è®°</a><a class="bds_tieba share-btn tieba" data-cmd="tieba" href="#" title="åˆ†äº«åˆ°ç™¾åº¦è´´å§">ç™¾åº¦è´´å§</a><a class="bds_linkedin share-btn linkedin" data-cmd="linkedin" href="#" title="åˆ†äº«åˆ°linkedin">Linkedin</a><div class="more"></div></div></div>
<label><img src="//static.cnbetacdn.com/share/r2.gif"/></label>
</div>
<div class="article-global"></div> </div>
```

If you observe, `div` with class `article-share-code` is a child node. If you delete the parent, all the child nodes too get deleted.

Hence, if you run the following code, the child node also gets deleted

```
res = requests.get("https://www.cnbeta.com/articles/tech/1097507.htm")
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text)
soup.find("div", {"class": "cnbeta-article-body"}).decompose()
```

Only to delete the `div` with class `article-share-code` check the following code

```
soup.find("div", {"class": "article-share-code"}).decompose()
```

Comment: I only want to delete `article-share-code` div and keep `cnbeta-article-body` div @bigbounty